# Javascript - merge properties of an object

Tags: javascript, kentico

I am trying to find out some elegant solution how to merge values of object's properties if the name is same.

Example:

```
var object = {
"10-10-2017": "Black friday",
"11-09-2017": "Some holiday",
"10-10-2017": "Fathers day"
}
```

Merge to:

```
var object = {
"10-10-2017": "Black friday Fathers day",
"11-09-2017": "Some holiday",
}
```

I use this object as a feed for calendar where property name is date and property value is/are events for the date and my solution cannot handle two properties with the same name. This feed is generated by template engine and it cannot can only render it this way (for each context of an event it adds a line to the object) when a view is rendered.

For those who know Kentico CMS I am using repeater with effect to build this object, where " var object = {" is html envelope before and "} " is html envelope after.

Comment: Your first object is not a valid object. You can’t have two keys with the same name.

Comment: ^^ The object initializer is valid, but the object only ends up with two properties, `10-10-2017` = `"Fathers day"` and `11-09-2017` = `"Some holiday"`. If you list the same property more than once in an initializer, the last one wins. So we can't help you, as the source object described only has two, not three, properties. There's nothing to merge.

Comment: how did your data get into this state? you'll probably need to resolve the duplication before creating any objects.

Comment: i'm confused though. what do you mean by merge? do you want to combine the events for each date so that each date can have multiple events under it?

Comment: better change your object to this form `{1:{id:123,value:"test1"},2:{id:123,value:"test2"}}`

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the OP has to programmatically build such an object line by line (each line a key value pair) within a template via the CMS, thus being not in control of preventing any kind of duplicates? If so, there might be a solution to it too.

Comment: @PeterSeliger yes you are right, I cannot control or prevent it

Comment: @LukDeathrageProchzka ... then [just check the already provided solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988952/javascript-merge-properties-of-an-object/46991133#46991133) for if it comes with an approach that does fit your environment / your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first edit I suggest that you change your object into other form
from

```
var object = {
"10-10-2017": "Black friday",
"11-09-2017": "Some holiday",
"10-10-2017": "Fathers day"
}
```

to

```
var object =[
{"date":"10-10-2017","value":"Black friday"},
{"date":"11-09-2017","value":"Some holiday"},
{"date":"10-10-2017","value":"Fathers day"}
]
```

If that helps you here's the working solution

```js
var object = [{date:"10-10-2017",value:"Black friday"},{date:"11-09-2017",value:"Some holiday"},{date:"10-10-2017",value:"Fathers day"}];

var output =[];

object.forEach(function(value) {
  var existing = output.filter(function(v, i) {
    return v.date == value.date;
  });
  if (existing.length) {
    var existingIndex = output.indexOf(existing[0]);
    output[existingIndex].value += ' '+value.value
    
  } else {
    if (typeof value.value == 'string')
      value.value = value.value;
    output.push(value);
  }
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(output)); //returns [{"date":"10-10-2017","value":"Black friday Fathers day"},{"date":"11-09-2017","value":"Some holiday"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the [question from my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988952/javascript-merge-properties-of-an-object#comment80928170_46988952) answers with *Yes*, this possibly provides a working approach ...

```js
// BEGIN of CMS templating ...

var descriptorList = [];

// programmatically push into a list of property descriptors,
// each descriptor holding just one key value pair.


  // +++ BEGIN iteration here ...

    descriptorList.push({ "10-10-2017": "Black friday" });
    // ...
    // ... keep looping ... "Kentico CMS repeater"?


    // for the sake of providing a working example
    // there will be some more descriptors pushed ...

    descriptorList.push({ "11-09-2017": "Some holiday" });
    descriptorList.push({ "10-10-2017": "Fathers day" });

  // ... END of iteration. +++


function mergeObjectsAndConcatSamePropertyStringTypes(a, b) {
  var
    type = Object.assign({}, a, b);       // - start with a raw merged type (merger).

  Object.keys(b).filter(function (key) {  // - collect `key` duplicates. 
    return (key in a);
  }).forEach(function (key) {             // - for each duplicate `key` that targets
    var aValue = a[key];                  //   a string type at each object, do concat
    var bValue = b[key];                  //   this values and assign it to the merger.
    if ((typeof aValue == 'string') &&/*||*/ (typeof bValue == 'string')) {
      type[key] = [aValue, bValue].join(' ');
    }
  });

  return type;
}

// assembling of the desired type ...
var type = descriptorList.reduce(mergeObjectsAndConcatSamePropertyStringTypes, {});

// END of CMS templating ...


console.log('descriptorList : ', descriptorList);
console.log('type : ', type);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -3):

First of all your code is not correct as JS will only picks up the last prop if name is same.

```
> var object = {
... "10-10-2017": "Black friday",
... "11-09-2017": "Some holiday",
... "10-10-2017": "Fathers day"
... }
undefined
> object
{ '10-10-2017': 'Fathers day', '11-09-2017': 'Some holiday' }
>
```

But

For the extra prop, there is an solution, hope this helps you, e.g. your

```
object[newProperty] = (object[newProperty] || '') + newValue;
```